# How to find an element using "substring or contains" of value of HTML Attribute in selector using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find an element using substring of HTML Attribute value in selector?

I am trying to find whether div contains an input with docnumber startes with letter 'S'

```js
 alert($("#forbDokProd").find(".dokMalProd input[name='check2'] [data-doknumber*='S'").length > 0)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="doc" class="docParent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" class="ballu" value="123" data-docnumber="S004"> <---Starts with S
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" class="ballu" value="123" data-docnumber="B004"> <---Starts with B
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" class="ballu" value="123" data-docnumber="B005"> <---Starts with B
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vfse1caL/1/

Not preferring For Each

Comment: Here you go, https://jsfiddle.net/vfse1caL/2/ use `[],[]` if you use space it looks for a child element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. It should not contain space between `[name=]` and `[data-doknumber]`. It also should be `^=` to only *starts with*:

```
".dokMalProd input[name='check2'][data-doknumber^='S']"
```

```js
alert($("#forbDokProd").find(".dokMalProd input[name='check2'][data-docnumber^='S']").length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="forbDokProd">
  <div id="doc" class="docParent dokMalProd">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" class="ballu" value="123" data-docnumber="S004">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" class="ballu" value="123" data-docnumber="B004">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" class="ballu" value="123" data-docnumber="B005">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

There are also other typos: missing closing `]`, wrong HTML structure and selectors.

Comment: Worked for me thanks. Let me test and will accept it as answer. I hope ^ will not do any problems in future

Comment: How to do exact oppsite like i do not want to choose element attribute contains S as name.?

Comment: @fatherazrael You need to use `input[name='check2']:not([data-doknumber*='S'])`

Comment: Kindly update it in your answer too for reference of readers :)

Answer (score 2):

The `[attribute^=value]` selector selects each element with a specific attribute, with a value beginning in a specific string. 
Remove the space between the selectors.

```js
console.log($("#doc").find("input[name='check2'][data-docnumber^='S']").length > 0)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="doc" class="docParent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" class="ballu" value="123" data-docnumber="S004"> <!---Starts with S-->
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" class="ballu" value="123" data-docnumber="B004"> <!---Starts with B-->
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" class="ballu" value="123" data-docnumber="B005"> <!---Starts with B-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are having a type error in your code, your using `docnumber` and `doknumber`

`alert($("#doc").find("input[name='check2'][data-docnumber*='S']").length > 0)`

**demo**

```js
console.log($("#doc").find("input[name='check2'][data-docnumber*='S']").length > 0)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="doc" class="docParent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" class="ballu" value="123" data-docnumber="S004">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" class="ballu" value="123" data-docnumber="B004">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" class="ballu" value="123" data-docnumber="B005">
</div>
```

Comment: Using comma would make it a multi selector